# Get daily Ad data using Facebook SDK/ Graph API, including the date

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Facebook's SDK and the Graph API to get Ad data from facebook.
I am getting the data in this format now:

```
account_id: "xxx"
account_name: "xxx"
adgroup_name: "xxx"
age: "xx-xx"
campID: "xxx"
campaign_name: "xxx"
clicks: 2
cpc: 0.3
cpm: 8.82352941176
ctr: 2.94117647059
date_start: "2015-06-01
"date_stop: "2015-06-28"
impressions: 68
spend: 0.6
unique_actions: 2
```

this is one row from the object they've sent me.

I am making the request like this:

```
 $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', 'act_' . $adAccount . '/reportstats?data_columns=["account_id","unique_actions","cost_per_action_type","account_name","campaign_id","campaign_name","impressions","clicks","spend","cpc","ctr","cpm","age","adgroup_name"]&format=json&async=true&time_increment=all_days&time_ranges=["{\'day_start\':{\'day\':\'' . $start_day . '\',\'month\':\'' . $start_month . '\',\'year\':\'' . $start_year . '\'}, \'day_stop\':{\'day\':\'' . $stop_day . '\',\'month\':\'' . $stop_month . '\',\'year\':\'' . $stop_year . '\'}}"]');
```

I am not getting the date of each of these rows. I want to have a specific date to see how many clicks, how much was spent  etc per day. is that possible?

Anyone?